# ArangoDB AQL: Traverse all graph edges without using startVertex

Tags: arangodb, aql

I have a scenario where I would like to loop over all the edges in an edge collection (1-depth traversal). Thus, in the query below, I don't want to specify the startVertex.

```
[WITH vertexCollection1[, vertexCollection2[, ...vertexCollectionN]]]
FOR vertex[, edge[, path]]
  IN [min[..max]]
  OUTBOUND|INBOUND|ANY startVertex
  GRAPH graphName
  [PRUNE pruneCondition]
  [OPTIONS options]
```

However, it seems this isn't possible. Is there some way to go about this? I know I could just perform a normal loop over the edge collection and retrieve the _from and _to vertices for each edge, but I'm worried about performance issues if I do this. I would appreciate any advice, especially for improving performance.

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? Are you just trying to get information from a single edge collection? Are you trying to get information from the vertex collections associated with the edge collection? Maybe a small example of what you are trying to achieve would be helpful.